# How do I show the number of times the biggest number was entered in C

Tags: c

So the objective of the program is to enter your grades from 1 to 20 (this part is easy so I haven't included the code) and, when you've entered all the grades, the program will calculate your average.

That's done. Now my problem is that I need to find the biggest number and tell how many times that number has been entered, and I don't see how I do it, and didn't find anything that could help me.

This is what I have:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int num, i, contador, avg, maior, maiorc;
    num = 0;
    i = 0;
    contador = 0;
    avg = 0;
    maior = 0;
    maiorc = 0;

    while (num != -1)
    {
        printf("Digite 3 ou mais notas e termine com -1: ");
        scanf("%d", &num);

        if (maior < num)
        {
            maior = num;
        }
        i = i + num;
        contador++;
    }
    if (contador > 3)
    {
        avg = (i + 1) / (contador - 1);

        printf("A média linear da turma é %d valores \n", avg);
        printf("Biggest value is: %d %d vezes \n", maior, maiorc);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("ERRO - Sequência Invalida \n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Please format your code to be readable.

Comment: What are you having difficulty with?  Determining which is the biggest value?  Or determining how many times it was entered?  You keep a record of the biggest value, and also a count of the number of occurrences.  When the biggest value increases, set the count to 1.  When the current biggest value reoccurs, increment the count.

Comment: I'm having difficulties with deterring how many time it was entered

Answer (score 0):

If, in your loop, you encounter a number larger than all other numbers you've seen so far, then that's the new largest number (`maior = num`), and this is the first time you've seen it (`maiorc = 1`).
If you encounter a number that's *equal* to the largest number you've seen so far, then that's an additional time you've seen that number (`maiorc++`).

```
if (maior < num)
{
    maior = num;
    maiorc = 1;
}
else if (maior == num)
{
    maiorc++;
}
```